# Determine the equation of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been battling with the following question:

Determine an equation for the plane that contains the line $x=-1+3t, y=5+3t, z=2+t$ and is parallel to the line of intersection of the planes $x-2(y-1)+3z=-1$ and $y=-2x-1$

I first wrote the line on the plane to be $L_1=(-1, 5, 2)+t(3, 3, 1)$

Then I worked out the line of intersection
$$
n_1=<1,-2,3>\\
n_2=<-2, -1, 0>\\
\\
v=n_1\times n_2\\
v=<3,-6,-5>\\
L_2=(-1,1,0)+t(0,-6,-1)
$$
I got the point by subbing in $z=0$, but now am confused at what to do next.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Take both direction vectors and the point of $L_1$ so  $$(-1,5,2)+s(3,3,1)+t(0,-6,-1)$$ is the desired plane.

Comment: Since you want a line parallel to $L_2$ you don't need to go though the step of finding a point on $L_2$ you just need to know the direction.

Comment: Your $v$ is not well calculated. Note that it is not perpendicutar to $n_1$ nor $n_2.$

Comment: What form is the equation supposed to be in?

Comment: @mfl Thank you for noticing that, I can see the mistake I made there.

Comment: @DougM Thank you for the tip, I will keep it in mind in future.

Comment: @amd It doesn't say, but I think in the form $ax+by+cz=d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the plane must contain the first line we get that $(-1,5,2)$ is a point of the plane and $(3,3,1)$ gives a direction.

Since the plane is parallel to the intersection of the other two planes we have that $$(1,-2,3)\times (-2,-1,0)=(3,-6,-5)$$ is another direction of the plane.

Thus its equation is

$$\begin{vmatrix}x+1 & y-5 & z-2\\ 3&3&1\\ 3&-6&-5\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I just want to make sure I'm changing the form correctly, since I want to use the form $ax+by+cz=d$. I got $-9x+18y-27z=45$, which I divided through by 9, to get $-x+2y-3z=5$

Comment: I think you have obtained the correct solution.